# Is it possible to update more than one database table with one form submission in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Let's say:

[ Micropost ] -> has_one -> [ MicropostPhotoAlbum ] -> has_many -> [ MicropostPhotos ]

If Micropost had one photo it wouldn't need a MicropostPhotoAlbum and I could just add an "image" column to my microposts table and work smoothly with carrierwave.

**My form below would work fine:**

```
   = form_for @micropost, :remote => true do |f|
        = f.file_field :image  # Needed for image previewing with html5 file api
        = f.hidden_field :user_id
        = f.text_area :content
        = f.submit "Post"
```

All I'd need to do is mount an upload to my micropost model and I'd be set. The image path would upload directly to the microposts table image column e.g. photo.png.

Well as you can see above each micropost won't have any photos but instead have one album that contains many photos. Now my form won't work seeing as there will be a micropost_album_id column instead of an image column.

How can I use my current form to upload a photos to the photos table and post my micropost content in one submit? Is there any simple way around this other than reverting back to making each micropost have one photo?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

[Here](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) is an (old, admittedly) article on nested attributes in forms. [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) is the key.

Comment: This is great! Reading that article made everything click instantly. I'm off to read the api and see what's been changed and how this is achieved in rails 3.2. Thanks